# Minecraft won't update past 1.5.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to log in on the first screen when you've double clicked the icon it says: "Can not connect to Minecraft.net" when I clearly have wifi. I have to play in offline mode which means I can't update it. Any help?

Comment: There is a difference between having wifi and having connection to the internet. Do you have the latest launcher version? Have you restarted your pc/laptop/whatever? What have you already tried to solve this problem?

Comment: So you're saying that when you select 1.5.1 in the launcher, it works, but not 1.6?

Comment: I dont see what is too broad or unclear. Theres a problem with his game, with the error message. Let's help this guy get back to his minecraft!

Comment: @Fredy31 He has not provided *nearly* enough information to actually answer the question. Answers are nothing more than guesses, and the whole point of closure is to ensure we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history

Minecraft 1.5.1 is now 4 years old. With the Microsoft Buyout, I guess the link to the updater has died. From web experience, they probably removed the server response a year or so after putting the new launcher online, and since you havent updated in years you are one of the installs that has been left behind.

Try to go and get a fresh version at https://minecraft.net/en-us/ (a Minecraft account will be necessary.)

PS: A good first step to verify if you have wifi is well, can you load a web page. But here there's also a catch. A page that was already visited could be loaded from cache. So go on google, and do a search for something like 'Dwarves Scandinavian Death Metal' or something really random that you havent searched before. If it could load results, you are connected. If it doesnt, well, you aren't.

If your Wifi is patchy, I would recommend connecting your PC/Laptop with a ethernet wire to your router. It should help with your connection issues. If you still have connection issues, contact your ISP.

Comment: Nope, old versions are still available and there are many people who use them occasionally. Microsoft has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Old versions are still available on the new launcher, however the old launcher isn't aware of the new location of the old versions.